# CSS/JS reset scroll position of a DIV inside an absolute DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm loading an image inside a div #popup, which is inside a main wrapper called `#main`

```
#mask {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and

```
#popup {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    max-width: 960px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #efefef; 
    height: auto;
    left: 80px;
    right: 80px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

with jQuery i load an image inside `#popup` and i can scroll it up and down, but  when i close the overlay and I load another image, the image is not visible form the top...it maintains the same scroll position when i left/close the first image...

dunno why...how can I reset it without resetting the whole page?

```
$('#popup').scrollTop(0);
```

seem is not working...

Comment: What about using an anchor tag on the top part of the popup to call it when the popup opens?

Comment: Or also the default scrollTop function (nonjquery) `var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
popup.scrollTop = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reset the scrolling of the wrong div, you should reset the scroll of the div that has the `overflow` property set.

In this case the div that handle the scroll is the `#mask` div, so apply the `scrollTop()` the `#mask` element.

`$('#mask').scrollTop(0);` will do the work.

Make sure the element (`#mask`) is already visible when calling the `scrollTop()` will not work.